# How to remove greyspace from carousel bootstrap

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4

there is a greyspace (gap) when I am trying to view the page in mobile/ other size, how do I remove the greyspace? all the images have the same height and width

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. But you need to provide us the code you have to let other people understand and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **Media Queries** or **Bootstrap-4 supported utitlies** like `p-md-0 m-sm-0`. Bootstrap-4 make use of Mobile-First-Design Approach, work accordingly.

This resource may help https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_utilities.asp